# Fade iPhone navigation bar when first cell goes off screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I'd like to have an effect like the foursquare venue page where the navigation bar starts clear, then becomes opaque when the top cell in the table scrolls out of view.  The twitter app has a similar effect in the profile tab.

How would this be accomplished?  Is there a way to know when a cell goes out of view (the opposite of `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` )  Or should should I check the scroll position of the table and make changes when the scroll position is at a certain value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, declare an ivar named lastOffset of type CGFloat.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat distance = lastOffset - scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    lastOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    CGFloat barHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    if (lastOffset > - barHeight) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectOffset(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame, 0.0f, distance);
        }];
    }
}
```